# how to display checkbox selected items in ascending order

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < check1.Items.Count; i++)           
    {               
        if (check1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            comment.Text = "\u2022 "+check1.Items[i].Text  +"<br/>"+ comment.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

For example if i have checkbox list:

`*apple`
`*Mango`
`*Orange`
`*Grapes`

and i have selected apple, orange and grapes it is displaying as

`grapes`
`orange`
`apple`

I want it to be displayed as:

`apple`
`orange`
`grapes`

Comment: Which control are you using, ListBox or what ?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it using Linq and make use of it

Example :

```
var sortedCheckBoxes = check1.Items.Where(c => c.Selected).OrderBy(c => c.Text);
```

Comment: What if you want to sort it no matter if the items are checked or not.. also .. do you have a VB.NET version of that .. I get errors when I convert your example to VB

Answer (score 0):

First store these items in a List then sort it and then set it to Coment.Text property

```
protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

 List<string> lst = new List<string>();

 for (int i = 0; i < check1.Items.Count; i++)
 {

    if (check1.Items[i].Selected)
    {           
       lst.Add(check1.Items[i]);            
     }           
  }

  lst.Sort();
  foreach(list l in lst)
  {
     comment.Text += l;
  }
 }
```